# I want to do div doesn't work unless I press it

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I want to do div doesn't work unless I press it, I call users using for loob.
I useing "onclick" but it work when page load

HTML code
`

```
 <main>
         <div class="conterner">

            <div class="users " >
               <div style="margin: 0 a;" id="parUser">
                  <div class="user" id="user" >
                     <h3 id="name"> Ahmed </h3>
                     <h3 id="email"> Ahmed.ali@gmail.com</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="infos">
               <div class="info">
                  <h5 class="postHead" > post post postpost</h5>
                  <div class="line"></div>
                  <p class="postP"> post post postpost</p>

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        
      </main>
```

`

JS code
`

```
 function getUsers(){

       fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
         .then((response) =>{
            if (response.ok) {
               return response.json() 
            }
         
         })
         .then((users) => {
            for(user of users){
               console.log(user)
               let orginalDiv = document.querySelector("#user");
               orginalDiv.style.display ='none';
               let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
               newDiv.innerHTML= orginalDiv.innerHTML;
               newDiv.className="user";
               let nameH = document.querySelector('#name')
               nameH.innerHTML = user.name;
               let emailH = document.querySelector('#email')
               emailH.innerHTML = user.email;
               const parentDiv = document.getElementById("parUser")
               parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
             **  user.onclick =userEvent();** I wnat when user click hear take to userEvent()
                
            }
          
                     return
         });

      }
```

`

**  user.onclick =userEvent();** I wnat when user click hear take to userEvent()

Comment: Remove the `()`: `user.onclick =userEvent;`

Comment: You mean `newDiv.onclick`, not `user.onclick` right?

Comment: I remove it but still had the same issue new code `newDiv.onclick = userEvent(); `  Yes, but how when I click on the div execution function `userEvent;();`  only now execution when load page ?